# No instance of Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.List in the implicit scope

Tags: json, scala, deserialization

I have nested case classes to deserialize a json object into object "C". THe json looks like this:

```
val jsonResp = {
 "parent":{
   "children": [
     {"name": "a",
      "house": "blue"}
     {"name": "b",
      "house": "green"}
   ]
 }
}
```

I have nested class to deserialize the values.

```
case class Parent(children: Children)
case class Children(children: List[Child])
case class Child(name: String, house: String)
```

I am trying to get the "child" object at 0th index here:

```
val parent = jsonResp.as[Parent](Json.format[Parent])
val childrenRespObj = jsonResp.as[Children](Json.format[Children])
val child1 = Child(ChildrenRespObj.children.head.name, Child(ChildrenRespObj.children.head.house)
```

Encountered error: No instance of Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.List in the implicit scope.

Since "Children" has List[Child] as a parameter then why its throwing the error? How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this play-json ? Although `Json.format[X]` generates the json format for any given type `X`, it needs json formats for all components of `X` to create it. Use `import play.api.libs.json._` to import the library provided `Reads`, `Writes` and `Format` instances.

Comment: I am using mport play.api.libs.json._ in the above example. Using this to format instances "(Json.format[Children])". I think it is not able to deserialize it into a List[Child].

Answer (score 2):

`Json.format` needs the dependency `Format`'s to be able to create the `Format` for dependent type.

You need to make sure that the dependency `Format`'s are available as `implicit` in the scope where the dependent `Format` is being created by `Json.format[...]`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object CustomJsonImplicits {
  implicit val childFormat = Json.format[Child]
  implicit val childrenFormat = Json.format[Children]
  implicit val parentFormat = Json.format[Parent]
}

import CustomJsonImplicits._

val parent = jsonResp.as[Parent]

val childAtZerothIndex = parent.children.children(0)
```

**Edit**

I just realised that your case classes are kind of wrong for this json. You have to keep in mind that the auto generated Format instances are very particular about json structure. Modifying for correctness.

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

// it is good practice to define case classes as final
// but this code will work the same even without final
final case class Response(parent: Parent)
final case class Parent(children: List[Child])
final case class Child(name: String, house: String)

object CustomJsonImplicits {
  implicit val childFormat = Json.format[Child]
  implicit val parentFormat = Json.format[Parent]
  implicit val responseFormat = Json.format[Response]
}

val jsonResp = 
  s"""|{
      |  "parent": {
      |    "children": [
      |      { "name": "a", "house": "blue" },
      |      { "name": "b", "house": "green" }
      |    ]
      |  }
      |}""".stripMargin

import CustomJsonImplicits._

val jsValue = Json.parse(jsonResp)

val response = jsValue.as[Response]

println(response)

val childAtZerothIndex = response.parent.children(0)

println(childAtZerothIndex)
```

Also, you can try running this code as a Scastie snippet at - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sarveshseri/dfBs6PvOT8KDTV4ITdTByA/9

Comment: I would use `headOption` _(or just `head`)_ rather than `(0)`

Comment: Note that most of the time we declare the implicit formatters in the companion object of the case class (if possible) so that they're picked up automatically. This is to apply only if the case classes are always (de)serialised the same way.

Comment: @sarveshseri Its throwing the same error at "implicit val childrenFormat = Json.format[Children]". It says "No instance of Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.List in the implicit scope." The Children class has List[Child] as an argument which probably the reason why its not able to figure that out.

Comment: I don't know what strange things are you doing as you should not have this error at all. You can find the working snippet at - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sarveshseri/dfBs6PvOT8KDTV4ITdTByA/9